# MultiRowRangeFilter: how to limit results per RowRange?

Tags: hbase, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to utilize the HBase `MultiRowRangeFilter` in order to minimize the number of round-trips to the server for repeated Scan attempts. However, I can't figure out how to handle the situation where one Row Range may have too many rows, which would prevent the `Scan` from returning any rows from other ranges.

For example, consider a table with the following Row Key structure and content:

```
Bob|1|XXX (XXX is some random sequence)
Bob|1|XXX
Bob|1|XXX
Bob|2|XXX
Bob|2|XXX
Bob|2|XXX
Bob|3|XXX
Bob|3|XXX
Bob|3|XXX
```

How in the above table could I do a `Scan` that would return MAXIMUM of 2 rows per each range of `Bob|~|` ?

Right now the dummy code looks something like this:

```
private void getRanges(Table tbl, Integer max) throws IOException
{
    List<RowRange> rowrangeList = new ArrayList<RowRange>();
    for (Integer i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        String rowKey = "Bob|" + i;
        RowRange rowRange = new RowRange(rowKey.getBytes(), true, rowKey.getBytes(), true);
        rowrangeList.add(rowRange);
    }

    FilterList fList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
    fList.addFilter(new KeyOnlyFilter());
    fList.addFilter(new FirstKeyOnlyFilter());
    fList.addFilter(new PageFilter(max));
    fList.addFilter(new MultiRowRangeFilter(rowrangeList));

    Scan s = new Scan();
    s.setFilter(fList);

    ResultScanner scanner = tbl.getScanner(s);
    for (Result row : scanner)
    {
        System.out.println("Got row: " + new String(row.getRow()));
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

But here are the problems:

This would work if we don't specify the `max` figure and omit setting `PageFilter(max)` in the `FilterList`. We could filter results on the client side, but the table might have millions of rows with `Bob...` row key prefix, so we want to limit the results of the `Scan` on the server side.

If we specify `PageFilter(max)`, then if the table has more rows than `max` with prefix `Bob|1|`, then we won't return any rows with prefix `Bob|2|` etc.

How can we best do this? Again, the goal is to do one `Scan` for multiple ranges at once (in order to improve the current functionality of doing repeated `Scans` for each of those sub-keys, which seems inefficient). Ideally this should work both with HBase and Bigtable, but at least one or the other would help!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this functionality isn't natively supported. My best suggestion would be to issue the row ranges in parallel. This will actually improve your overall latency, because multiple row ranges in a single read request are processed in sequence.

Going this route will slightly reduce your maximum throughput due to per-RPC overhead. But if you're streaming back more than a handful of rows per range the work will be dominated by response processing, so you shouldn't see much difference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this code snippet was meant to run at a Worker level in Spark already (i.e. it couldn't be parallelized further from this stage). This might be possible in Beam though, which we might be using at some point later.

Answer (score 0):

How many rows will Bob|1 have? If it doesn't grow unbounded, then maybe you can adjust your schema so that Bob|1 is the row key and the XXX is a column name. Then you can use ColumnPaginationFilter to limit the number of columns to 2?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I can't change the schema this way, because there can be many Bob|1 rows, so won't be unique. But thanks for bringing up the ColumnPaginationFilter -- it might be useful for other purposes here...